# How rollout undo works during rollingUpdate strategy when deployment has crossed 'progressDeadlineSeconds'?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment

I have created a kubernetes deployment with below specs:

```
replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
```

Algorithm of the rollout and undo that I'm experimenting:

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
if(kubectl rollout status deployment != 0)
{
   kubectl rollout undo deployment
}
```

I'm trying to test the failure case.

Initially we have 2 pods old-pod-1 and old-pod-2. We initiate a rolling deployment with above configuration to maintain at least 2 pods at all times. So, when we initiate the deployment, an additional pod is created with the new code (new-pod-1).  Let us say this succeeds.  At this time, One old pod is brought down(old-pod-1 is down). Now if the 2nd new pod deployment fails, what would happen?

Adding some background:
In a test where new-pod-1 creation is unsuccessful, after progressDeadlineSeconds new-pod-1 is killed and after rollout undo we will be left with old-pod-1 and old-pod-2.

But in the above case, old-pod-1 is already down. thus, what is the end state of the pods? Will we have a pod created with old deployment version?

Comment: did you rollout to which version exactly the recent number or recorded number when deploying? ideally you should be rollingout to older version and pods should be up and running.

Comment: @Sravs2725 If your  issue is solved , can you please provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as answer for the greater visibility of the community.